# Use elementary complex analysis to show that the bijectivity of a FLT implies that all coefficients are real up to multiplication.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

I've looked at a couple of answers to a similar question; I get how to prove bijectivity if we know that the coefficients are real and $ad-bc > 0$. That's actually fairly simple.

What I don't get -- and what I suspect I'm overthinking -- is how to prove the converse, i.e. --

*that a fractional linear transformation $$\frac{az + b}{cz + d}$$ has real coefficients up to multiplication by a constant, with $ad - bc > 0$ on top and bottom if it is bijective UHP $\rightarrow$ UHP.*

At this point I've thrown just about everything at the wall and am spinning my wheels. I did prove that $ad - bc\neq 0$ (and thus one can multiply top and bottom by constants whose product is $\overline{ad-bc}$, but I lost my notes on how I did it.

As for the second part:

- First I tried assuming injectivity, surjectivity, and the existence of an inverse and tried to derive a contradiction, but that led me mostly to (apparently) useless results.  For example, if $d\neq 0$ and one takes the limit of the functionas $z\rightarrow 0$ then we have that $b / d$ has to be in the closure of the UHP, i.e., $Im(b\overline{d})$ has to has to have strictly negative imaginary part.  Or, e.g., in order for the function to be a function we have to have $-d/c$ not in the upper half-plane.  Not terribly helpful.
- I tried making "real up to multiplication by a constant" mathematically precise, but that just sent me into a bunch of logical circles.
- Finally, I tried using the fact that the function has to map the real line onto the real line.  If we multiply the denominator by its conjugate then we get that a polynomial in $|z|$, $z$, and $\overline{z}$ has to be real for all real values of $z$.  That, too, doesn't do much much good.

**Edit** Since I know more advanced complex analysis, I reasoned that the desired function would map the boundary, $\mathbb{R}$, to itself; i.e., it would map three distinct real points $a$, $b$, and $c$ to $0$, $1$ and $\infty$ respectively.  So in that way we obtain a FLT with real coefficients, although I used the result that $ad - bc\neq 0$ in the proof.

However, I found this problem in Ch 1 of Greene & Krantz's book and so I suspect that there is a much, MUCH simpler answer that I just overlooked.  Can anyone help?

Comment: without loss of generality, you can restrict to $ad-bc= 1$

Comment: @user1952009 I might need a more specific hint.  I get why this is true but don't see the connection to bijectivity without using more advanced properties of FLTs.

Comment: I wrote a [proof for the unit disk](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940464/finding-the-mobius-transformation-that-maps-open-unit-disk-onto-itself/1941331#1941331) yesterday, so adapt it, or more direct, pick a [Möbius biholomorphism $\phi : H \to D$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119881/form-of-most-general-transformation-of-the-upper-half-plane-to-the-unit-disk), and use that for every Möbius biholomorphism $\gamma : H \to H$, $\ \ \phi \circ \gamma \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a Möbius biholomorphism $D \to D$

Comment: And $ab-cd \ne 0$ is obvious, since otherwise it is not invertible (the inverse is $\frac{Az+B}{Cz+D}$ where $\begin{pmatrix} A&B \\C& D \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\c& d \end{pmatrix}^{-1} =\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix} d&-b \\-c& a\end{pmatrix}$ )